# How to Upload Image files Using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

How to Upload Image files Using Codeigniter?
[Codeigniter's Upload class Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

gives no hint for how to upload a image using simple form and upload the image to it's images folder which is present in the root directory...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That page actually does explain everything you just asked. User uploads image into form box, CI parses it and downloads it onto server.

Comment: How can I remove this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example. Hope this would help you :)

in your controller. lets say `upload.php`

```
public function upload() {
    if($this->input->post('upload')) {

        $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . 'your upload folder name here/'; 
        $config['file_name'] = filename_here;
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config["max_size"] = 1024;
        $config["max_width"] = 400;
        $config["max_height"] = 400;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {               
            $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        } else {
            //success                                      
        }  
    }
}
```

Then in your view

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload'); ?>    
<?php echo form_upload('userfile'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');?>    
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: File uploads are an essential process in many web apps. Almost every website and web app requires an integrated file upload component.I have found this https://www.cloudways.com/blog/codeigniter-upload-file-image/