# how to upload image from codeigniter to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

I am new in CodeIgniter. I am not getting how to update form data in the database. Insertion and showing data from database is done but can't understand how to update data in the database.

I've tried researching this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719477/how-to-upload-image-files-using-codeigniter) but data not successfully uploaded.

This is my **Controller**

```
//npwp
$temp1 = explode(".", $_FILES['file_npwp']['name']);
$new_name1 = time().'.'.end($temp1);
$config1['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'/file_npwp/';
$config1['file_name'] = $new_name1;
$config1['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config1['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
$this->load->library('upload',$config1);
$this->upload->initialize($config1);
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file_npwp')){
$this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

}
$media1 = $this->upload->data('file_npwp');
```

This is my **Model**

```
$data_service['file_npwp']= $file_lampiran1;
$data_service['file_ktp']= $file_lampiran2;
$data_service['file_po']= $file_lampiran3;
$data_service['file_registrasi']= $file_lampiran4;
$this->db->where('id_service',$this->input->post('id_service'));
$this->db->update('service_sis', $data_service);
```

This is my **View**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">File NPWP</label>
<input type="file" name="file_npwp" id="file_npwp" class="form-control">
</div>
<br>
<div id="hasilloadfoto"></div>
<br>
<p>*Pastikan semua form sudah terisi dengan benar</p>
<button id="SaveAccount" class="btn btn-success">Simpan</button>
```

This is my **Javascript** in my view

```
$( function() {
var $signupForm = $( '#myForm' );
$signupForm.validate({errorElement: 'em'});
$signupForm.formToWizard({
submitButton: 'SaveAccount',
nextBtnName:  'Selanjutnya',
prevBtnName:  'Sebelumnya',
nextBtnClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-flat next',
prevBtnClass: 'btn btn-default btn-flat prev',
buttonTag:    'button',
validateBeforeNext: function(form, step) {
var stepIsValid = true;
var validator = form.validate();
$(':input', step).each( function(index) {
var xy = validator.element(this);
stepIsValid = stepIsValid && (typeof xy == 'undefined' || xy);
});
return stepIsValid;
},
progress: function (i, count) {
$('#progress-complete).width(''+(i/count*100)+'%');
}

});
});

function filePreview(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
$('#hasilloadfoto + img').remove();
$('#hasilloadfoto').after('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="450" height="300"/>');
}
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#file_npwp").change(functio () {
filePreview(this);
});
```

Need help in update operation. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do in two ways,

1. You can upload the image to any cloud storage(Aws, Azure, etc) then update the link on your Db
2. Convert the image into base64 and update it as the string on your DB.

I will prefer to go with step one, I have the sample where I have uploaded it to Azure and update my DB

// This is on Js , Using ajax , I will send to controller
 function uploadImage() {

```
    var base_url = '<?php echo BASEURL ?>';
    // call ajax to upload image
    //event.preventDefault();
    var file_data = $('#post-image').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('uploaded_file', file_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "dashboard/uploadImage",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (aData) {

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

}
```

On Controller ,

> public function uploadImage() {
>
> // get the 'api-key' key from Request Headers
>
> ```
>     $data = array();
>     if (isset($_FILES ['uploaded_file']['name']) && !empty($_FILES ['uploaded_file']['name'])) {
>         $userId = $this->input->post("userId");
>
>
>         $file_name = $userId . "_" . uniqid() . ".jpg";
>         $S3ImgUrl = uploadImageToS3($_FILES ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], "app_feed_images", $file_name);
>
>
>         $data = array(
>             'code' => 555,
>             'message' => 'Image has been uploaded successfully',
>             'url' => $S3ImgUrl
>         );
>     } else {
>         $data['code'] = -111;
>         $msg = "failed to upload image to s3";
>         $data ['status'] = $this->failed_string;
>     }
> ```
>
> // var_dump($data);
>           echo json_encode($data);
>       }

Helper Class

> function uploadImageToS3($tmp, $bucket, $file_name) {
>
> ```
> $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" . azure_bucket_name . ";AccountKey=" . azure_bucket_key;
> $blobClient = MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);
> $containerName = "app-image/" . $bucket;
> $containerUrl = "https://hbimg.blob.core.windows.net/";
>
> $content = fopen($tmp, "r");
> $options = new MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CreateBlockBlobOptions();
> $content_type = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
> $options->setContentType($content_type);
> $blobClient->createBlockBlob($containerName, $file_name, $content, $options);
> return $containerUrl . $containerName . "/" . $file_name; }
> ```

On the controller side, I have just uploaded the image, you can call you model class with the uploaded image link and update on your DB.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I mean, if the data that previously existed in the database server I want to replace it and if the data doesn't already exist, I want to fill it with uploading the file. Thank you for the help

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to send the name of the photo in database right then in model you have to add

```
$this->input->post('databse_column_name')=$variable_name_which_content_file_name
```

Comment: $this->input->post('id_service')=$data_service; cannot running because error code: Message: Can't use method return value in write context

Filename: models/Muser.php

Comment: i can edit code : $this->input->post('id_service',$data_service). This is running no message error, but dont uploaded data to enter the database to replace the existing data.